# Debug libraries are linked to the release version of the app with CMake+msbuild

Tags: cmake, msbuild

I have a CMake file that link two libs in the following way:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} debug ${ANGLE_LIB_DIR}libEGLd.lib ${ANGLE_LIB_DIR}libGLESv2d.lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} optimized ${ANGLE_LIB_DIR}libEGL.lib ${ANGLE_LIB_DIR}libGLESv2.lib)
```

when I run msbuild with MSVS2015 solution file built with CMake, debug library libGLESv2.lib is linked to the release version of the app, so app crashes. Debug version of the app links to debug version of the libs and works fine.

The commands I use are:

```
cmake ..\..\examples\src\MyApp\ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\Repos\install -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015\lib\cmake
msbuild MyApp.sln /property:Configuration=Debug
msbuild MyApp.sln /property:Configuration=Release
```

Comment: You need to prepend every single library with a `debug` or `optimized` keyword.

Comment: good! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specifying libraries in the `target_link_libraries` command for a single configuration (debug | optimized) you need to specify the configuration for every single library, e.g.

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} debug ${ANGLE_LIB_DIR}libEGLd.lib debug ${ANGLE_LIB_DIR}libGLESv2d.lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} optimized ${ANGLE_LIB_DIR}libEGL.lib optimized ${ANGLE_LIB_DIR}libGLESv2.lib)
```

You could start your builds then also with CMake using the following commands:

```
cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config Debug
cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config Release
```